# How to attach pdf to my mail generated by python 2.4.3 script?

Tags: python

I've searched about attaching a pdf in my script but I found the answer, which is, correct me if I'm wrong, using MIMEApplication, not compatible with python 2.4.3. I couldn't import MIMEApplication, and didn't find it in the documentation. I don't have the option of upgrading my OS to accept newer version.

Here is my code so far:

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from smtplib import SMTP

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromAddr
msg['To'] = ",".join(toAddr)
msg['Subject'] = msgSubj

bodyFile = open(bodyFilePath, "r")
msg.attach(MIMEText(bodyFile.read()))
bodyFile.close()

attachFile = open(attachFileDir+attachFileName, "r")
msg.attach(MIMEText(attachFile.read()))
attachFile.close() 

# ... send msg using SMTP
```

Any help, please?

Comment: The basic `email` library is fine for creating a message with attachments. Do you have peculiar needs which somehow are not met by this approach?

Comment: Python 2.4 is extremely old, though.

Comment: I'm trying to attach a pdf or even txt file. When I use MIMEText, it attaches the text  as written text in the mail, not the file itself. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Without access to your code or the generated message, this is pure guesswork; but sounds like you are missing a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header in the generated MIME part.

Comment: If the Python library is too old to be useful - which I doubt, but I know it was overhauled significantly at some point before 2.5, which is the oldest version I can remember - hard-coding or reimplementing some part of the process is not terribly complicated. The basics of MIME are simple and it's all just text, although you should probably have it reviewed by someone with a bit of domain knowledge. The hard part is the mound of legacy - many ways to do the same thing, some of which are cumbersome and/or not widely supported in clients.

Comment: Show us your code and (the interesting parts of) the source of your message so that we can get out of pure speculation.

Comment: Though `MIMEText` is only suitable for text parts (plain or HTML, basically). For a PDF, you want `application/pdf` (though there are several common legacy types as well; see above). A message with just an attachment is possible and simple to do, but a common arrangement is a multipart with a brief text part to explain the purpose of the message, then the attachment part.

Comment: **Here is my code**

from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from smtplib import SMTP
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromAddr
msg['To'] = ",".join(toAddr)
msg['Subject'] = msgSubj
bodyFile = open(bodyFilePath, "r")
msg.attach(MIMEText(bodyFile.read()))
bodyFile.close()
attachFile = open(attachFileDir+attachFileName, "r")
msg.attach(MIMEText(attachFile.read()))
attachFile.close()

**then send through smtp**

Comment: Sorry for the format.

Comment: @tripleee
The first file, bodyFile, is the msg body. I want to read it and paste its contents to the mail, which is achieved here.
The second file, attachFile, is the attachment. I want to attach it as it is, which is not the case here. This is what I want to know how to do it.
Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information. Paste your code, select the pasted block, and type ctrl-K to format it properly. Python code in comments is unfortunately rather useless.

Comment: As suggested already above, you want `MIMEApplication`, not `MIMEText`, for the PDF attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Like you are saying, it appears that [the `email` module in Python 2.4.3](https://docs.python.org/release/2.4.3/lib/module-email.html) does not support `MIMEApplication()` for creating an `application/*` MIME part.

I *think* you might be able to override attributes manually, something like

```
from email.Encoders import encode_base64
# other imports as in your code

pdf = MIMEText(attachFile.read())
attachFile.close()
pdf.set_type('application/pdf')
pdf.set_charset(None)  # remove ; charset= attribute
pdf.set_param('name', attachFileName)
pdf.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=attachFileName)
encode_base64(pdf)
msg.attach(pdf)
```

This is a bit of a crock, but it seemed to work in my brief test.

Comment: The received file can't be opened.
The OS tills me the following:
**The filename "Abdelrahman_Darweesh_W13.pdf" indicates that this file is of type "PDF document". The contents of the file indicate that the file is of type "plain text document". If you open this file, the file might present a security risk to your system.**

Comment: Again, could you please post the source of the problematic message?  Which OS is generating this warning?  What does the file look like before sending?  Is it mangled when you receive it?

Comment: I've tried to open the file through Python and print its contents but the result was bunch of random characters.

Comment: The PDF format is "a bunch of bytes" (though of course they are not "random").  What you can do is run `file` on the file and examine the result, do a hex dump and try to compare, etc.

Comment: I don't know how to get the source code. I've searched the documentation and found `getsourcelines` but couldn't use it. Any help, please?

Comment: The message source is just the raw text of the email message.  In most email clients, you can "view source" to see the textual, MIME representation of the message.

Comment: Here is the plain text part:
`Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============0130033828341427185=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: python@gmail.com
To: python2@gmail.com
Subject: new test8

--===============0130033828341427185==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Dear Eng,


Hello from Python world



Regards,

h

--===============0130033828341427185==
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="W8.pdf"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="W8.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`

Comment: The rest is too big to be in a comment.
Answering your questions, the OS is CentOS 5.7, the original file is a one paper PDF contains text, and yes, the received file is mangled. I did a hex dump to the original and the received and they are totally different.

Comment: If you run `base64 W8.pdf` on the CentOS server, does the output correspond with what you have in the email?  (If you don't have `base64`, implementing it as a simple Python script should be just a couple of lines of code.)

Comment: `from base64 import b64encode
from os import chdir
chdir(path)
a = open("W8.pdf", "r")
b = open("enc_msg.txt", "w")
b.write(b64encode(a.read()))
a.close()
b.close()`
This is what I did to the original file. The output is different from the received one! I've compared them through a hex dump.

Comment: Not sure what's up with that. If you experimentally attach a simple text file, does that get through properly?

Comment: I've just tried that. The received text file has survived when I decoded it, without decoding, the received file is encoded.

Comment: I've tried to decode the received pdf, but no response, still corrupted.

Comment: I don't think Python 2.4 had proper Unicode support, but an incorrect encoding while reading in the file is just about my only remaining speculation. If you read the PDF and then write it out to a different local file, is that different from the original?

Comment: When I read a PDF and write its contents in a new file.pdf, that new pdf is a duplicate of the original and has no problems!

Comment: I'm running out of ideas here. If you can repro this with a "hello world" PDF which you can share here, please update the question with those diagnostics.